# Flutter - an async function returns before really finishing?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a function `scanAndConnect()` that should scan for BLE devices and connect to the device with the specified service ID. This function should be `async` and should return Future.

The problem is that `scanAndConnect()` prints `99999` and returns without waiting for `flutterReactiveBle.statusStream.listen()` to finish although I use `await` before it.

```
Future scanAndConnect(Uuid serviceId, Uuid charctId) async {
    StreamSubscription<BleStatus>? bleStatusStreamSubscription;
    StreamSubscription<DiscoveredDevice>? deviceStreamSubscription;
    Stream<DiscoveredDevice> stream;
    bleStatusStreamSubscription =
        await flutterReactiveBle.statusStream.listen((bleStatus) async {
      print("new listen ${bleStatus.toString()}");
      if (bleStatus == BleStatus.ready) {
        await bleStatusStreamSubscription!.cancel();
        connectionStatus = BLEConnectionStatus.Connecting;
        stream = await flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices(
          withServices: [serviceId],
          scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency,
        );
      }
    });

    print("9999999");
  }

....

Future connectToDevice() async {
  await ble.scanAndConnect(BLE_SERVICE_UUID, BLE_CHAR_UUID)
  print("Statement after await in main");
  setState(() {
    loading = false;
    print("Changing state to ${loading.toString()}");
  });
}
```

This is the output I get in Xcode:

```
flutter: 9999999
flutter: Statement after await in main
flutter: Changing state to false
flutter: new listen BleStatus.unknown
flutter: new listen BleStatus.ready
```

How can I make `scanAndConnect` doesn't return before really finishing?

Comment: `listen` registers a callback.  It returns a `StreamSubscription`, not a `Future`. `await`ing it will not tell you when the callback executes (and isn't correct anyway since it's not a `Future`).  If don't want your function to complete until after your callback executes, you can have it complete a `Completer` and let your function `await` that `Completer`'s `Future`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_reactive_ble/latest/flutter_reactive_ble/FlutterReactiveBle/scanForDevices.html), `FlutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices()` returns a `Stream`, not a `Future`, so `await` will not work here. You can use

- `await for`
- `listen()`
- `await stream.first()`

to wait for data from a `Stream`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried `await for` and it works. But it keeps iterating in the `stream` block. How can I `cancel` it when done as it is done using ` bleStatusStreamSubscription!.cancel();` in the code above?

Comment: @Salahuddin There is no need to cancel a stream subscription when using `await for`. (In fact, you might consider using `await for` with `statusStream` as well, instead of `listen`.) If you need to exit the `await for` loop before the stream has concluded, you can do so using the `break` keyword.